# Missing field when deserializing using Jackson (Polymorphic)

Tags: java, jackson

I am trying to create an java SDK for a front-end library that takes JSON input. Essentially, this SDK converts objects of certain type into JSON which is then consumed by that front-end library.

I am using jackson's polymorphic serialization/deserialization using its annotation system.

I have a base class A and 2 child classes B and C extending A. Class A has a type field, using which I decide what class (B or C) is to be used. The syntax looks something like this:

```
@JsonTypeInfo({
  use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, 
  include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY,
  property= "type"
})
@JsonSubTypes({
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = B.class, name = "b"),
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = C.class, name = "c")
})
public class A {
  private String type;

  public void setType(String type){
    this.type = type;
  }

  public String getType(){
    return this.type;
  }
}

public class B extends A {

}

public class C extends A {

}
```

So now, when I use Jackson's `ObjectMapper`'s `readValue` function and read the stringified JSON and convert to class A, I get the correct instance of either class A or class B based on the value of the type variable. **However**, and here is the actual problem, when I try to use the function `getType` I always get `null` in those objects. I am not sure why jackson is not setting those values on the object.

```
String json = "{ type: 'b' }"; // example input json

ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
A a = om.readValue(json, A.class);
// a is actually an instance of class B

a.getType()// this is null
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add to `@JsonTypeInfo` the parameter `visible = true` to avoid to remove the type when deserializing.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
  use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, 
  include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY,
  property= "type",
  visible = true
)
```

> public abstract boolean visible() default false
>
> Property that defines whether type identifier value will be passed as part of JSON stream to deserializer (true), or handled and
>   removed by TypeDeserializer (false). Property has no effect on
>   serialization. Default value is false, meaning that Jackson handles
>   and removes the type identifier from JSON content that is passed to
>   JsonDeserializer.

Comment: thanks, works! not sure how i missed it in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks a ton for this.